# force use of specific passwords

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, password, security

We are migrating Active Directory from from Windows Server 2003 to 2008 shortly. With 2008 we would like to be able to use a separate password policy for a particular group of PCs. One suggested password policy would force users to choose a new password from a predefined list when a password expires. So we would then effectively be rotating between 3 passwords.
I know this doesn't seem like a good idea and I am proposing a different solution. But can this be done? Can we use Active Directory to store the viable passwords for a particular PC?

Comment: This is pretty much dead-set *against* best practices, so I don't know how you would implement this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you describe is known as a [Password Filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms721882%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  The default Windows Password Filters do not provide the exact functionality you're asking for.  You will need to either [code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms721884%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) your own, or purchase a third party implementation.

A quick Google search should return many third party commercial options, I am hesitant to link any one specific vendor as this topic gathers spam-links too frequently.  [This SourceForge project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/passwdhk/) may be a decent starting point should you build your own.

Comment: That's right - I forgot about Password Filters. Never seen a custom one in use.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible with Active Directory, the only similar Policy is to compare the new password against the last X number of set passwords and prohibit it's application if it matches any of them. The only way I can suggest is an excel spreadsheet visible only to the administrator who would then apply the password.